# Phrases for placing emphasis

Tags: word-choice

Scientific writing often involves writing down a list of facts.

I frequently come across a situation where I need to point out a fact or an observation that is not obvious, and sometimes not completely connected with the previous sentence.

I mostly use "Note that..." followed by the observation. I am looking for variations to open a sentence in a similar way. I tried looking at charts related to cohesion, linking phrases etc. but did not come across any category that precisely provides me with substitutions for "note that".

Comment: Can you post a few example sentences you would like to link?

Comment: Sure. Here is an example:

(Description of some diagram). Note that as x increases in the range 50 to 200, unlike in the previous figure, y increases with it until x reaches 200 at which point, y starts to decline.

Something like that.

Comment: Have you considered *not* using an opening phrase?  For example:  (Description of diagram) *X increases in the range 50 to 200, but unlike in the previous figure . . .*  The word *but* serves as your link here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about style/writing advice.

Comment: Don't overdo it -- that's my advice. If you really want X to stand out then do not try to make Y, Z, A, B, C, and D stand out also. Choose wisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some opening phrases you could employ:

**You will note**
**Please be aware**
**Of note**
**Interestingly**
**By contrast**
**The reader will note**
**As you can see**
**It should be apparent that**

I think that these could fit into the example you've given above.

This list is by no means exhaustive.

Comment: Thanks for the useful substitutions. "Please be aware" sounds a little like a request and slightly personal.

Comment: @Turingmachine You could drop the "Please" without causing too much trouble, I think.